Get correct paragraph separation along with hyphenation in tcolorbox?
In this example, I have two tcolorbox environments. I discovered that the parskip package does not work correctly unless I set the parbox=false parameter. However, this setting causes hyphenation to fail, leading to some long words exceeding the box's width.
To summarize:

The first solution provides acceptable spacing between paragraphs but fails to manage hyphenation properly.
The second solution is visually unappealing but supports hyphenation.
How can I achieve both good paragraph spacing and proper hyphenation?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[many,minted]{tcolorbox}% version 3.03 or better
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox{callout}[1][]{%
    breakable,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{callout}[parbox=false]

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id odio nunc.
  Suspendisse potenti. Integer et elit ut sem convallis gravida.

  Donec porta tincidunt dapibus. Donec id enim nec ante cursus consequat in nec libero. In maximus ante enim, et pretium velit scelerisque eget. Morbi iaculis egestas justo in faucibus.

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit pré-fuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.
  \item Nullam id odio nunc.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{callout}

\begin{callout}[hyphenationfix=true]
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id odio nunc.
  Suspendisse potenti. Integer et elit ut sem convallis gravida.

  Donec porta tincidunt dapibus. Donec id enim nec ante cursus consequat in nec libero. In maximus ante enim, et pretium velit scelerisque eget. Morbi iaculis egestas justo in faucibus.

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit pré-fuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.
  \item Nullam id odio nunc.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{callout}

\end{document}


I am aware that in §4.18 it says:

that parbox=false and hyphenationfix should not be used together. They are targeting different box types and they do not blend very well.


This has nothing to do with tcolorbox: TeX will not hyphenate past an explicit hyphen, unless you explicitly tell it to.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  many,
  %minted, % <--- not needed for the example
]{tcolorbox}% version 3.03 or better
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox{callout}[1][]{%
    breakable,
    #1
}

\providecommand{\allowhyphens}{\ifvmode\else\nobreak\hspace{0pt}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{callout}[parbox=false]
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id odio nunc.
  Suspendisse potenti. Integer et elit ut sem convallis gravida.

  Donec porta tincidunt dapibus. Donec id enim nec ante cursus consequat in
  nec libero. In maximus ante enim, et pretium velit scelerisque eget. Morbi 
  iaculis egestas justo in faucibus.

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        pré-supercal\-i\-frag\-i\-lis\-tic\-ex\-pi\-al\-i\-do\-cious
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        pré-\allowhyphens supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
  \item Nullam id odio nunc.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{callout}

\end{document}

Either you specify optional hyphenation points or allow hyphenation past the explicit hyphen. I'd prefer the first way, where you can better control that the hyphenation doesn't come too early (not as many \- are necessary).

Note. I commented out the minted option because it's irrelevant for the problem and would require shell escape for no reason.
